# Entering into the wrong If statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

the program does not enter the if statement it suppose to enter.for example when the sentence1 is oguzhan and the sentence2 is bugrahan for first characters it should enter the first if statement end substitution should be 4 but it doesn't.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  char sentence1[50];
  char sentence2[50];
  int m, n, k, l;
  int i, j, substitution;
  cout << "Enter the first word:" << endl;
  cin >> sentence1;
  cout << "Enter the second word:" << endl;
  cin >> sentence2;
  m = strlen(sentence1);
  n = strlen(sentence2);
  int cost[m + 1][n + 1];
  cost[0][0] = 0;

  for (i = 1; i < m + 1; i++) {
    cost[i][0] = cost[i - 1][0] + 2;

  }
  for (j = 1; j < n + 1; j++) {
    cost[0][j] = cost[0][j - 1] + 2;

  }

  for (i = 1; i < m + 1; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < n + 1; j++) {

      if ((sentence1[i - 1] == 'a' || sentence1[i - 1] == 'u' ||
           sentence1[i - 1] == 'e' || sentence1[i - 1] == 'i' ||
           sentence1[i - 1] == 'o') &&
          (sentence2[j - 1] != 'a' || sentence2[j - 1] != 'u' ||
           sentence2[j - 1] != 'e' || sentence2[j - 1] != 'i' ||
           sentence2[j - 1] != 'o')) {
        substitution = 4;
      }

      if ((sentence1[i - 1] != 'a' || sentence1[i - 1] != 'u' ||
           sentence1[i - 1] != 'e' || sentence1[i - 1] != 'i' ||
           sentence1[i - 1] != 'o') &&
          (sentence2[j - 1] == 'a' || sentence1[i - 1] != 'u' ||
           sentence1[i - 1] != 'e' || sentence1[i - 1] != 'i' ||
           sentence1[i - 1] != 'o')) {
        substitution = 4;
      }

      if (sentence1[i - 1] == sentence2[j - 1]) {
        substitution = 0;
      }

      if ((sentence1[i - 1] == 'a' || sentence1[i - 1] == 'u' ||
           sentence1[i - 1] == 'e' || sentence1[i - 1] == 'i' ||
           sentence1[i - 1] == 'o') &&
          (sentence2[j - 1] == 'a' || sentence2[j - 1] == 'u' ||
           sentence2[j - 1] == 'e' || sentence2[j - 1] == 'i' ||
           sentence2[j - 1] == 'o')) {
        substitution = 3;
      }
      if ((sentence1[i - 1] != 'a' || sentence1[i - 1] != 'u' ||
           sentence1[i - 1] != 'e' || sentence1[i - 1] != 'i' ||
           sentence1[i - 1] != 'o') &&
          (sentence2[j - 1] != 'a' || sentence2[j - 1] != 'u' ||
           sentence2[j - 1] != 'e' || sentence2[j - 1] != 'i' ||
           sentence2[j - 1] != 'o')) {
        substitution = 3;
      }

      cost[i][j] = min(min(cost[i - 1][j] + 2, cost[i][j - 1] + 2),
                       cost[i - 1][j - 1] + substitution);
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < m + 1; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) {

      cout << cost[i][j] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  cout << sentence1[0];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you debug and see the values of both when it did that? Also, what if someone enters more than 49 characters?

Comment: Too much code. Too little time.

Comment: how is this supposed to work? is it valid c++? `int cost[m+1][n+1];` what compiler are you using gpp?

Comment: This will always be true `if((sentence1[i-1]!='a'||sentence1[i-1]!='u'` because a character can't be both `'a'` and `'u'` at the same time.

Comment: Delete as much code as you can and still have a valid example. See [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @kupto some compilers allocate space on stack to achieve this as a feature, which is not required by C/C++ spec.

Comment: Consider writing the function `bool is_a_vowel( char c )` once and watch your code get smaller and more understandable.  (With fewer errors!)

Comment: @Kupto, The OP's compiler supports C++14 already :p

Comment: It enters into first, second and fifth if statements.

Comment: If your task is more complicated consider to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A condition like: `sentence2[j-1]!='a'||sentence2[j-1]!='u'` is always true -- no single character can be equal to both `a` and `u`, so one of these has to be true.

If you're using `!=`, it must almost always be joined by `&&`, not `||`, otherwise the result will always be true, regardless of input.